# Do local variables in lua occupy memory after end of scope?

Tags: memory, lua, local

--script.lua
local x = 0

--main.lua
dofile("script.lua")

Now we are out of script.lua scope, so we can't directly access x variable. But it still exists and its definition occupies memory even if x == nil.
How can I delete x completely? Or How can I load thousands of scripts to do some stuff and release these scripts one by one completely?
I dont need their locals in my memory anymore

The only thing that worked is BAD EVIL globals. If i use global x = 0, then x = nil do what i want, but every pro lua user keep saying that globals are bad.

Comment: Why do you think it stil exists?

Comment: 1. if I define global functions increment_x() and get_x() in script.lua and then run them in main.lua, they will return 1. So, lua still keeps x value in memory. And  if you write "local x = nil" 201 times, you'll get an error "too much locals"

Comment: It is precisely because of these two functions that x always exists? If you have too much "local x = nil" in one function, I bet you will still see the error. You need to read this: [Garbage Collection](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5)

Comment: but numbers are not subject to garbagecollect.

Comment: "If i use global x = 0, then x = nil do what i want, but every pro lua user keep saying that globals are bad" - nitpick: setting fields to nil does *not* reclaim any memory, or even enable the GC to collect any memory, because Lua allows deleting fields while traversing tables. Only *adding* new fields lets Lua rehash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those locals are still referenced by the global functions.

[[...] inaccessible from Lua means that neither a variable nor **another live object** refer to the object.](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5)

And that reference is, if I understood correctly, a upvalue:

[When a C function is created, it is possible to associate some values with it, thus creating a C closure [...]; these values are called upvalues and are accessible to the function whenever it is called.](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.2)

Comment: So those are upvalues!
♂Ahhh♂, thank you so much, Mister!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found this in "The implementation of Lua":
--Once a closed upvalue is no longer referred by any closure, it is eventually garbage collected--
Click noice!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).